# Query the Google image JSON API and save the first result to the documents folder. Is it free?

Tags: image, url, search, download, uiimage

I'm implementing this code to perform a Google Image Search (based on specific input keys such as "fuzzy monkey") and save the first result to the documents folder.

References:
https://gist.github.com/nickyEnjoysWoogoo/5458128

```
//URL requested is a search term "fuzzy monkey" only percent escaped...
NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:
[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey"]]
                                  returningResponse:&urlResponse
                                          error:nil];

// The request returns a LIST in a json format...
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                             error:nil];

NSLog(@"first image's url: %@", result[@"responseData"][@"results"][0][@"url"]);


// In the gist it only extracts the first hit of the list...
NSData *dataImage = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:result[@"responseData"][@"results"][0][@"url"]]] returningResponse:&urlResponse
                       error:nil];

//Then it downloads that image and saves it on the device...
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
[dataImage writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/monkey.jpg", [paths objectAtIndex:0]] atomically:YES];
```

My question is: Is this a "free" service provided by Google ?

As per "Pricing" section in developer google website:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview?csw=1

**JSON/Atom Custom Search API pricing and quotas depend on the engine's edition:**

**Custom Search Engine (free)**

**For CSE users, the API provides 100 search queries per day for free. If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the Developers Console. Additional requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per day.**

**Google Site Search (paid).**

**For detailed information on GSS usage limits and quotas, please check GSS pricing options.**

I'm not sure if this applies to the specific case I'm presenting.

I think there is a difference between the "Google Custom Search API" (which uses "www.googleapis.com") and this "ajax.googleapis.com".
Indeed I'm not passing any key/username/password in my request and the result is provided. The tutorials only suggests to pass parameter "userip" to detect automated requests but the user ip does not appear to be used to count the number of searches for billing purposes.

So, can I include the link ajax.googleapis.com for free in my code and be sure that end users wont have any issues/errors when running ?

Answer (score 1):

ajax.googleapis.com no longer works. use www.googleapis.com

edit:
in response to comment stating this is not an answer:

OP asked: "My question is: Is this a "free" service provided by Google ? "

The answer is: no, it does not work anymore.

OP asked: "So, can I include the link ajax.googleapis.com for free in my code and be sure that end users wont have any issues/errors when running ?"

The answer is: no, it does not work anymore